# Why my view isnt rendering all (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby on Rails, and I am currently working on my first project. However, here is my problem:

If the user is creating an account without valid information, I want to show him what the problem was.

But my form isn't rendering the information.

**Controller:**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def userlist
    @users = User.all
  end

  def newuser
    @user = User.new
  end 

  def create_new_user
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to users_userlist_path
    else
      puts @user.errors.full_messages
      @user = User.new(user_params) 
      render 'users/newuser'
    end
  end

  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username,:userpw,:email)
  end
end
```

**view:**

```
<%= if @user.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h1><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h1>
    <ul>
    <% puts user.full_messages %>
    <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
      <li><%= message %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= form_for @user, url: { action: "create_new_user" }, namespace: "users" do |f| %>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <%= f.label :username %>
    <%= f.text_field :username %>
  </div>

  <div class="mb-3">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.text_field :userpw %>
  </div>

  <div class="mb-3">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>

  <div class="">
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

By the way, the `puts` statement is working!

I'm only getting the output from the `puts` statement

Answer (score 1):

You overwrite the user instance after your puts in the controller:

```
@user = User.new(user_params)
```

This removes the previous validation and thus the errors. Removing that line should resolve your issue